# Using Javascript to grab element on remote page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to grab an element from a remote HTML page. As I am requesting data from a different domain I am using the below code to add the source as a script. Yes, very dodgy.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'http://remoteDomain.com/page.html');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

The above code fetches and appends the entire page to my document head. Seems to work okay. However now I would like to able to grab an element by ID, or even regex from this source.

Can this be done?

I am aware that the above code is dirty, so I'd be happy to receive any suggestions to clean it up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed very dodgy... But there are crossdomain AJAX tehniques that you can use. Some help here: http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: Worth noting that the 'screen scraping' solution using YQL actually requests the page via a yahoo server, not via the client browser. Unfortunately I need a client side scrape to get dynamically generated elements.

Answer (score 0):

> The above code fetches and appends the entire page to my document head.

It doesn't really, it just creates a `script` element of which its `src` points there.

It looks like you are trying to get around [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Can you use a server side proxy?

Comment: unfortunately can't go server side.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers go to great lengths to prevent this being done client-side unless the site you're trying to read explicitly opts in.

Otherwise any random web page you visit could read info from your bank account, say.